# MaterializeCSS Port FeatureDiscovery css to angular material

Tags: angular-material, materialize

Is there any way to port the css code or create a new css similar to FeatureDiscovery from [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html) and embed on [angular material FAB](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial)?